# Last content is remain in TinyMCE

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I use `TinyMCE` as `Html` editor in a `ASP.NET` application. I insert some text in editor and save in database. When I go to the page to insert some new text, the text in last step still remains in editor.
Why last content remains in `TinyMCE`, even in different .aspx pages? How I do clear the content?

Answer (score 1):

Simply should remove `autosave` from `plugins`